# Reading and passing JWT in Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift

I need to pass JWT token in order to get access to the data. How do I do it?
I see the token in the console, but there is nothing in the tableView.
What I actually want is:
- Authenticate the user
- Get the JWT token
- Display the relevant courses

```
         import UIKit
         import Alamofire

 class AvailableCoursesTableViewController: UITableViewController {

let url = "https://api.sis.kemoke.net/auth/login"
var parameters = ["email": "kemoke@hotmail.com", "password": "passwd"]
var token : HTTPHeaders = ["X-Auth-Token": ""]

//Custom struct for the data
struct Courses {
    let course : String

    init(dictionary: [String:String]) {
        self.course = dictionary["course"] ?? ""
    }
}

//Array which holds the courses
var courseData = [Courses]()

func authenticate() {
    Alamofire.request(url, method: .post, parameters: parameters, encoding: URLEncoding.httpBody, headers: nil).responseJSON {
        (response) in
        self.token["X-Auth-Token"] = response.description
        print(self.token)
}
}

// Download the courses
func downloadData() {
    Alamofire.request("https://api.sis.kemoke.net/student/course", headers: token).responseJSON { response in
        print(response.request)  // original URL request
        print(response.response) // HTTP URL response
        print(response.data)     // server data
        print(response.result)   // result of response serialization

        //Optional binding to handle exceptions
        self.courseData.removeAll() // clean the data source array
        if let json = response.result.value as? [[String:String]] {
            for course in json {
                self.courseData.append(Courses(dictionary: course))
            }
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is not really about JWT tokens, it is about a specific API expecting certain parameters, please update the question

Answer (score 2):

To download courses you have to put token in following way:

```
// Where otherParameter is any other parameter you want to pass 
func downloadData(token : String, otherParameter : String)
{

    let url: String = "https://api.sis.kemoke.net/student/course"
    var request = URLRequest(url:  NSURL(string: url) as! URL)
    request.httpMethod = "POST"
    request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
    let values: [String: Any] = ["otherParameter": otherParameter,"token": token]
    request.httpBody = try! JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: values)
    Alamofire.request(request)
        .response { response in
            let jsonData = JSON(data: response.data!)
            print(jsonData)
            print(response)
            //Error check
            //check if error is returned
            if (response.error == nil) {
            // Write your required functionality here 

            }
}
```